# How to make a list of random numbers that never repeat (consecutively) in swift ui

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I have created this code to make a list of random, but never repeating (when next to each other) numbers.
The issue is that the `Text(String(numbers[i]))` line gives an index out of range error because the array doesn’t have all its values yet.
I am very new to swift ui, and I can’t figure out how to accomplish something like this. Thanks in advance

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var numbers: [Int] = []
    @State var previousNumber = Int()
    @State var randomNumber = Int()
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(0..<100) {i in 
                Text(String(numbers[i]))
            }
        }.navigationTitle("numbers")
        .onAppear() {
            for i in 0 ..< 100 {
                previousNumber = randomNumber
                randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0...9)
                while randomNumber == previousNumber {
                    randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0...9)
                }
                numbers += [randomNumber]
            }
            print(numbers)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To create a simple monotonic array of random numbers, just start with a positive random value - say random(1...9) -, add it to the array, then create a new positive random value and let the next element be the sum of this and the last one, and so on. Of course, there are numerous ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd move your numbers into their own model (I'm using `NumberModel`) so that they can have unique IDs, which will make them more convenient to use in the `List`/`ForEach` (especially if they end up changing values over time). This will also allow you to just use `ForEach(numbers)` and not deal with the indices at all.

You don't need `@State` variables for `previousNumber` and `randomNumber` because they're just used within `onAppear`. I've refactored your `onAppear` a bit, but you could definitely go further with it.

```
struct NumberModel : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var number : Int
    
    var stringValue : String {
        number.description
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var numbers: [NumberModel] = []
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(numbers) { i in
                Text(i.stringValue)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("numbers")
        .onAppear() {
            var previousNumber : Int? = nil
            for _ in 0 ..< 100 {
                while true {
                    let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0...9)
                    guard randomNumber != previousNumber else {
                        continue
                    }
                    previousNumber = randomNumber
                    numbers.append(NumberModel(number: randomNumber))
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check if `numbers` is not empty.

I also made a few adjustments:

- Removed unneeded `@State` variables. You are also iterating a loop 100 times updating the state variables, multiple times per iteration. This is not a good idea. Notice `tempNumbers` is used to create the array, which then only updates `numbers` once.
- Used a `repeat ... while` loop for neater and less repeated code.
- Fixed issue where the first number could never be `0`, because you already have it set as the previous number.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var numbers = [Int]()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            if !numbers.isEmpty {
                ForEach(0 ..< 100) { i in
                    Text(String(numbers[i]))
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("numbers")
        .onAppear {
            var tempNumbers = [Int]()
            var previousNumber: Int?
            var randomNumber: Int?

            for _ in 0 ..< 100 {
                previousNumber = randomNumber

                repeat {
                    randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0 ... 9)
                } while randomNumber == previousNumber

                tempNumbers.append(randomNumber!)
            }

            numbers = tempNumbers
            print(numbers)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the `repeat { } while` -- that's not something I often think of using.

Answer (score 1):

My bias is to crate the view with the data you care about right off the bat and not put the logic in the view that would generate the view's own state. This will make it easier to understand as well.

### Extensions

To do this, I'm going to create a quick extension on INT that will create an array full of random numbers to the specified length.

```swift
extension Int {
    static func randomList(withLength length: Int) -> [Int] {
        var numbers: [Int] = []
        while Set(numbers).count < length {
            numbers.append(random(in: 0...length * 3))
        }
        return Array(Set(numbers))
    }
}
```

Then in the view we would do this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    // This will create the array when the view is created. You won't need
    // to do any manipulations in the onAppear method
    @State var numbers: [Int] = Int.randomList(withLength: 100)
    @State var previousNumber = Int()
    @State var randomNumber = Int()
    var body: some View {
        List{
            ForEach(0..<numbers.count) {i in
                Text(String(numbers[i]))
            }
        }.navigationTitle("numbers")
        .onAppear() {
            print(numbers)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This enforces unique numbers with a Set instead of allowing for duplicates. You could modify the function to do things a little differently if you want duplicates.

Comment: Could be even `let numbers: [Int] = Int.randomList(withLength: 100)` - if numbers will not be mutated from within the view.

Comment: The `length * 3` seems a little bit arbitrary. Especially in an extension.

Comment: It is absolutely arbitrary. I just wanted to reduce the opportunity for duplicate numbers because I wanted to display a set.

Comment: With this solution you risk having a performance problem. The more your `Set` grows, the more the `Int.random()` function is likely to generate an already existing element.
This may be better: `Array((1 ... length * 3).shuffled()[0 ... length - 1])`

Comment: @Adrien no need to instantiate a new array. `(1 ... length*3).shuffled()`
 You can also just use a range operator instead of closed range and subtracting 1 `[0..<length]`

Comment: @Jake note that converting your numbers result to a set and back to an array you will loose the numbers appended order.

Comment: @LeoDabus : Jake's function is a returning an Array, not an ArraySlice

Comment: @Adrien yes but he is discarding the order it was appended. A set has no order.

Comment: @Adrien If he wants a set just shuffle a range of integers

Comment: This approach IMO is very low quality and has nothing to do with what is being asked